# use Django filter but not working?

Tags: django, html, django-views

I made a template to put some posts on it, each post has two category, I use `<a>` to be the options, like:

```
    <div class="cate">
    <span class="cate_span0">Species：</span>
    <a href="?kind={{ post_kind }}">
    <span class="cate_span {% ifequal animal_kind '' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">All</span>
    </a>
    <a href="?animal=dog&kind={{ post_kind }}">
    <span class="cate_span {% ifequal animal_kind 'dog' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">Dog</span>
    </a>
    <a href="?animal=cat&kind={{ post_kind }}">
    <span class="cate_span {% ifequal animal_kind 'cat' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">Cat</span>
    </a>
    <a href="?animal=other&kind={{ post_kind }}">
    <span class="cate_span {% ifequal animal_kind 'other' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">other</span>
    </a>
<br/>

<span class="cate_span0">Article：</span>
<a href="?animal={{ animal_kind }}">
<span class="cate_span {% ifequal post_kind '' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">All</span>
</a>
<a href="?kind=new_explorer&animal={{ animal_kind }}">
<span class="cate_span {% ifequal post_kind 'new_explorer' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">Stray</span>
</a>
<a href="?kind=tell_story&animal={{ animal_kind }}">
<span class="cate_span {% ifequal post_kind 'tell_story' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">Story</span>
</a>
<a href="?kind=giving&animal={{ animal_kind }}">
<span class="cate_span {% ifequal post_kind 'giving' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">Post</span>
</a>
<a href="?kind=want&animal={{ animal_kind }}">
<span class="cate_span {% ifequal post_kind 'want' %}chosen_animal{% endifequal %}">Want</span>
</a>
</div>
```

And in my views I use `kind` and `animal` filter the DB:

```
animal_kind = request.GET.get('animal', '')
    post_kind = request.GET.get('kind', '')
    if animal_kind:
        all_posts = all_posts.filter(animal_cate=animal_kind)
    if post_kind:
        all_posts = all_posts.filter(post_cate=post_kind)
```

And:

```
        return render(request, 'community.html', {
        "all_posts" : posts,
        "animal_kind" : animal_kind,
        "post_kind" : post_kind,
        })
```

my models:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
POST_CATE_CHOICES = [
    ('GV', 'giving'),
    ('WT', 'want'),
    ('NE', 'new_explorer'),
    ('TS', 'tell_story'),
]
ANIMAL_CATE_CHOICES = [
    ('DOG', 'dog'),
    ('CAT', 'cat'),
    ('OTHER', 'other'),
]
user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, related_name='user_name', verbose_name=u"所属用户")
icon = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, related_name='user_icon', verbose_name=u"用户头像")
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"帖子标题")
content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u"帖子内容")
add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name=u"发帖时间")
image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to='post_img/%Y/%m', null=True, verbose_name=u"贴图")
post_cate = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=POST_CATE_CHOICES, verbose_name="帖子类型")
animal_cate = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ANIMAL_CATE_CHOICES, null=True, verbose_name="动物类型")
comment_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=u"评论数量")
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=u"顶")
dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=u"踩")
```

my posts:

```
{% for post in all_posts.object_list %}
<div class="post">
    <a href="" class="user_a">
    <img class="icon" src="{{ post.icon.icon.url }}">
    <span class="name_span">{{ post.user.username }}</span>
    </a>
    <span class="time">发表时间：{{ post.add_time }}</span>
    <span class="clicked">回复：{{ post.comment_num }}</span>
    <a href="">
    <img class="post_img" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.image }}">
    <div class="article">
    <h3 class="title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <span class="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ post.content }}</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It seems like only the `animal_kind`actually working and it can filter the exact item, but when I filter the `post_cate`, it's empty.
I don't where the problem is, maybe is my view because when I choose the option, the url is correct.

Comment: please shoe your models and posts

Comment: I put my post model and the post div

Comment: for post_cate what are you passing ?? like GV or giving? and for animal_cate what are you passing through the url DOG or dog?

Comment: passing the lower case like `giving` and `dog`, but store as `GV` and `DOG`, I use the same method but only animal_cate actually filtered

Comment: try passing GV or gv and check once

Comment: It's working, but is that mean my `choices` is not working?

Comment: yes, actually it is trying to match the value with the database but as you are having gv and not giving in the database thus it cant retrieve the values

Comment: OK, I Understand <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the filter is not returning any value as the matched values are not present in the database,

Your are storing `GV` in the `database` for `post_cate` but for `animal_cate` you are storing `dog` which is similar to the key `'DOG'`, thus it is working.

so you need to change the format of post_cate choices to `('GIVE','give')`